# Instagram API Media endpoint stopped working

Tags: instagram-api

I was using Instagram API media endpoint successfully for last few months, in my app, where users could search for a keyword and find images with the keyword from Instagram, loaded in my app. The function stopped working suddenly few days ago. I didn't make any changes to my code and I checked that my client with Instagram developer account is active and no changed occurred there either. I played with other endpoints such as "user_recent_media" and "Instagram.location_search("37.7808851", "-122.3948632")" and they worked. But something like "Instagram.location_recent_media(514276)" doesn't load anything. In summary, most of the endpoints with media is not working.
  I am in sandbox mode in Instagram, and is using my own instagram account to get access token. Since it was working perfectly, unless Instagram changed their sandbox mode policy, I dont' think it should be the problem. I didn't find any mention of policy change in last one week or so.
  I will really appreciate any help to solve this problem.
  My app is built on Ruby on Rails and below is the code, I used for media search, that was working perfectly, but stopped working couple of days ago:

In my controller, I have the method:

```
def index

    access_token  = "1660809866.7316e02.67583a7a1d7042318d137a65993d5432"
    client = Instagram.client(access_token: access_token)
    default_search = client.tag_search('travel')
    if params[:q]
      search_query = client.tag_search(params[:q])
      @tag = search_query.present? ? search_query : default_search
    else
      @tag = default_search
    end
    @tag = @tag.first.name
    @search = client.tag_recent_media(@tag)

  end
```

My Instagram.rb file is as follows:

```
require "instagram"
  Instagram.configure do |config|
  config.client_id     = "21b3d488b9404fa59ecf0b86d78****"

  config.access_token  = "1660809866.21b3d48.409f26bf818342829918450****"

 end
```

In the view file, I have following lines of codes to show the search box and show search results:

```
<div class="col-sx-6 col-md-3 col-md-pull-6">
      <h4>Instagram Lookup</h4>
    <br>
    <form class="search-box">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input id="search" type="text" name="q" class ="center-block form-control" title="Search Photos" placeholder="Enter keyword">
        <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-md btn-primary" type="submit"> Go </button></span>
      </div>
    </form>
    <br>
   <% @search.each do |popular| %>
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <%= image_tag popular.images.low_resolution.url %>

        <div class="caption">
          <% user_link = "https://www.instagram.com/" + popular.user.username.to_str %>
          Posted by: <i> <%= link_to popular.user.username, user_link, :target => "_blank" %> </i>
        </div>
      </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: try actual API call with your access_token in browser, it works: `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=1660809866.7316e02.67583a7a1d7042318d137a65993d5432`

Comment: Hi krisrak, I didn't get it working in my browser, not sure why. Also, how do I get the list of media with my search keyword so that I can display them in my app?

Comment: dont copy paste it, something wrong with characters, copy to sublime, check and then to browser

Comment: @krisrak :  "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=1660809866.7316e02.67583a7a1d7042318d137a65993d54**" works in browser. I have done testing with different Instagram API endpoints and found that, I can access all the media that was posted from my account. But if I want to access media by location or recent popular media etc., I get empty results. Basically, it looks like I am not able to access public contents . But I checked that my access token  have scope "Public_content" .  Please help.

Comment: are u in sandbox mode or live mode? in sandbox mode u will only get results from your account and your sandbox users account.

Comment: I am in sandbox mode. My understanding is that in Sandbox mode, I should have access to public content through my Instagram account. In other words, whatever my Instagram user account can access, I should have access to those through my app. It was working that way for last few months, until it just stopped working about a week ago.

Comment: you will only see your posts and your sandbos user's post in API response. so search a location where you or your sandbox user has posted, then only that posts will show in API response, when u go live, all posts will be in API response

Comment: hi..are you able to fix this issue?I am also facing similar issue for my app.It was working perfectly till last week but now it returns empty result.